# Better Approach for CLUSTERED vs NONCLUSTERED Primary Key

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table with below columns:

Id int identity,
UserId

What would be the better approach:

```
Making Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
Creating NONCLUSTERED Index on UserId
```

OR

```
Making Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
Creating NONCLUSTERED Index on UserId, Id
```

OR

```
Making Id PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
Creating CLUSTERED Index on UserId
```

OR

```
Making Id PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
Creating CLUSTERED Index on UserId, Id
```

OR

```
Just making a composite CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY including both columns Id, UserId
```

**Update**

Update/Delete is based on UserId and Id where as retrivals are based on UserId.

I mostly read from the table by userid. Since one user can have multiple records in this table, and in order to modify a particular record of a user for example for update/delete operations, I would need id and userid to uniquely identify the record.

Comment: We'd need the full table definition and queries you plan to run against it to be able to really answer. But there's not much of a difference between most of the options.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have added some more details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- option 1 is default option, I mean I would recommend to do it without
  knowing anything
- option 2 is the same as option 1 - same space utilization, same plan
- option 3 is good if you HAVE to have id as primary key but mostly
  read from the table by userid
- option 4 have the same drawbacks from option 3 but more expensive for
  other nonclustered indexes. The only good thing about it - it won't
  have 4 bytes 'make it unique' addon.
- option 5 is good if you can change definition of primary key and
  reference to your table is fine to have compound key (userid, id).
  Make sure the order is (userid, id) and not (id, userid)

In option 5 - if there is a child table it should reference not just by id but by userid and id

```
alter table child_table add constraint fk foreign key (user_id, parent_id) references mytable
```

**Update**
Based on the above answer of SergeyA and Dan Guzman's comment. It seems the option 5 i.e. composit key (userid, id) is the best option. Because
it will likely optimize retrieving rows by UserID and also update/delete operations when both columns are specified.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details reply. I mostly read from the table by userid. Since one user can have multiple records in this table, and in order to identify a particular record of a user for example for update/delete operations, I would need id to uniquely identify the record. Additionally, this table has other columns as well, and reading by userid would cause a Lookup in case of option 3, right?  So in this case which one would be better among option 3 and option 5? Can you please also elaborate "option5: reference to your table is fine to have compound key"?

Comment: in option 3 you AVOID lookup searching by userid. But there will be some fragmentation after inserting rows.

Comment: @NaveedAhmed, without seeing the actual queries, a composite clustered primary key on UserId, Id will likely optimize retrieving rows by UserID and also update/delete operations when both columns are specified.

Answer (score -1):

**Making Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED and Creating NONCLUSTERED Index on UserId:**

- Best option if you query based on userid.

**Making Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED and Creating NONCLUSTERED Index on UserId, Id:**

- Only useful when queries involve both UserId and Id.

**Making Id PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED and Creating CLUSTERED Index on UserId:**

- Better option if you filter using userid

**Making Id PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED and Creating CLUSTERED Index on UserId, Id:**

- It will be suitable when querying both userid and id, however be cautious about insert/update, as performance will be impacted due to the clustered index.

**Making a composite CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY including both columns Id, UserId:**

- If you are using joins on both columns, this step will be useful.